# Figuring out the function of cascade of ternary operators?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, ternary-operator

I'm trying to implement a simple (and easy to understand) version of *Merge Sort* and after a bit of research [I found the following *C* version](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#C):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge (int *a, int n, int m) 
{
    //...
    int i, j, k;

    // allocate memory on the heap for the temp array
    int *x = malloc(n * sizeof (int));

    // what is happening here (sorting)
    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0; k < n; k++) 
    {
        x[k] = j == n      ? a[i++]
             : i == m      ? a[j++]
             : a[j] < a[i] ? a[j++]
             :               a[i++];
    }

    // deep copy of temp elements to initial array
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        a[i] = x[i];
    }

    // free temp array
    free(x);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
void merge_sort (int *a, int n) 
{
    // base case (subarray with 2 elements)
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    // find index of middle element
    int m = n / 2;

    // divide into two
    merge_sort(a, m);
    merge_sort(a + m, n - m);

    // sort and merge
    merge(a, n, m);
}

//=====================================================================
int main ()
{
    int a[] = {4, 65, 2, -31, 0, 99, 2, 83, 782, 1};
    int n = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d%s", a[i], i == n - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
    }

    merge_sort(a, n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d%s", a[i], i == n - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could someone help me describe and comment (possibly break it into `if` statements) the long cascade of ternary operators in the `for` loop in function `merge`?

<sub>Content is available under GNU Free Documentation License 1.2 unless otherwise noted.</sub>

Comment: You provided a 10 sample example, maybe you could follow with a debugger ?

Comment: Well, `L = E ? E1 : E2;` maps to `if (E) L = E1; else L = E2;` so it's not that hard to unravel.

Comment: hint : `if(j == n || i == m  || a[j] < a[i]) x[k] = a[i++]; else x[k] = a[i++];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you didn't catch has nothing specific to do with merge sort:

```
    x[k] = j == n      ? a[i++]
         : i == m      ? a[j++]
         : a[j] < a[i] ? a[j++]
         :               a[i++];
```

Has just been written by someone that prefer sexy/funny looking code over readiness. BUT REAL CODE HAVE LINES. This could/should be expressed as:

```
if(j == n)
{
    x[k] = a[i++];
}
else if(i == m)
{
    x[k] = a[j++];
}
else if(a[j] < a[i])
{
    x[k] = a[j++];
}
else
{
    x[k] = a[i++];
}
```

If you need to understand how merge sort works see [Merge Sort on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort):

[image]

---

I've modified a bit the code to do *old fashion debugging*, and used the numbers of the GIF so you can follow, but first here's the output:

```
Pass 1. n:2, m:1
inserting 5
inserting 6

Pass 2. n:2, m:1
inserting 1
inserting 3

Pass 3. n:4, m:2
inserting 1
inserting 3
inserting 5
inserting 6

Pass 4. n:2, m:1
inserting 7
inserting 8

Pass 5. n:2, m:1
inserting 2
inserting 4

Pass 6. n:4, m:2
inserting 2
inserting 4
inserting 7
inserting 8

Pass 7. n:8, m:4
inserting 1
inserting 2
inserting 3
inserting 4
inserting 5
inserting 6
inserting 7
inserting 8
```

And now, the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int pass = 0;
void merge (int *a, int n, int m) {
    int i, j, k;
    int *x = malloc(n * sizeof (int));

    printf("\nPass %d. n:%d, m:%d\n", ++pass, n, m);

    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if(j == n)
        {
            printf("inserting %d\n", a[i]);
            x[k] = a[i++];
        }
        else if(i == m)
        {
            printf("inserting %d\n", a[j]);
            x[k] = a[j++];
        }
        else if(a[j] < a[i])
        {
            printf("inserting %d\n", a[j]);
            x[k] = a[j++];
        }
        else
        {
            printf("inserting %d\n", a[i]);
            x[k] = a[i++];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = x[i];
    }
    free(x);
}

void merge_sort (int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int m = n / 2;
    merge_sort(a, m);
    merge_sort(a + m, n - m);
    merge(a, n, m);
}

int main () {
    int a[] = {6, 5, 3, 1, 8, 7, 2, 4};
    int n = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d%s", a[i], i == n - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
    merge_sort(a, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d%s", a[i], i == n - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your answer has some typos. Also -- I don't think that the original code is all that hard to read.

Comment: @JohnColeman feel free to correct typos :). I also don't find it hard to read, but 3 years ago it would have been harder

Comment: Maybe its a double-standard, but I have always felt hesitant to edit answers in a way that I am not hesitant to edit questions. The reason I didn't find the code all that hard to read is precisely because it uses indentation so clearly. If the programmer had written that assignment in a single line I would both find it hard to read and object to it.

Comment: @JohnColeman I've added comments and indentation to show effort in understanding it, unfortunately the meaningless variable names and the high level of compactness and optimization make the code look good but hard to understand.

Comment: @Ziezi Utter speculation on my part, but perhaps the programmer has some experience programming in Lisp. That use of the ternary operator reminded me a bit about how a `cond` expression is typically laid out in Lisp code

Comment: @Ziezi You are merging two sorted arrays into a single target array. `k` is the index of the target array and `i` and `j`are the indices of the two arrays which are being merged into the target array.

Comment: I didn't add comments but I added (IMO) something more valuable so you can understand what it does @Ziezi